# Issue allowing new character to Regex

Tags: regex

**Current Regex:**

```
^([\d-]*[A-z]?|[A-z]?[\d-]*|[\d-]*[A-z]?[\d-]*){3}$
```

*(Allows a max of 3 letters and any amount of numbers or hyphens)*

I want to also allow the forward slash(/) to be just like the hypen(-), where there can be no limit, but i am doing something wrong, it doesnt match the following sequence.

**Updated Regex:**

```
^([\d-]*[\d/]*[A-z]?|[A-z]?[\d-]*[\d/]*|[\d-]*[\d/]*[A-z]?[\d-]*[\d/]*){3}$
```

*(Allows a max of 3 letters and any amount of numbers or hyphens or forward slashes)*

**Good:** 1234-aAa/

**Good:** 1234/aAa-

**Bad:** 1234aAa/-

This only happens when i add a hyphen after the forward slash and 3 alpha letters, what is wrong with my updated regex? The order doesnt matter for any characters, its just to the total overall characters in the string. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this here

```
^(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){0,3}[^a-z]*$)[a-z0-9/-]*$
```

See and test it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vp9a)

I use only `a-z` and the IgnoreCase option because `A-z` is not `[A-Za-z]`, there are some characters more inbetween.

So, basically my regex matches everything `[a-z0-9/-]*` I allow in the character class at the end.

This part `(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){0,3}[^a-z]*$)` is a positive lookahead, that ensures your requirement of max 3 letters. See [here for more about lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)